# Which of these Pokemon should I evolve?

Tags: pokemon-go

I am level 18 in Pokemon go. I have a 407 CP Squritle and a 188 CP Wartortle.

Which should I evolve to produce a higher level Blastoise?

Comment: how many candies do you have? Go for the squirtle if you have at least 125 candies, if not, w8 until you have those, but that squirtle looks pretty strong

Answer (score 10):

Pick Squirtle because he is higher level than Wartortle.

The cost of evolving Squirtle into a higher level Wartortle is only 25 candy.

The cost to power up Wartortle to Squirtle's level will cost you *at least* 26 candy + 19,600 stardust.

---

**Here's how I estimated the cost**

By looking at [this chart](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/19iql4aABmZ5oZ6YDE3LmZ8qcth3UoH52954WhjuiJow/edit?pref=2&pli=1#gid=1488557536), I can estimate what level a pokemon is from its CP. The exact level cannot be known unless you know the pokemon's IV (Individual Values).

- Squirtle 407 CP can be level 14.5 - 18
- Wartortle 188 CP can be level 4.5 - 5

This means Wartortle is at least 9.5 levels behind Squirtle, or as many as 13.5 levels behind.

*Assuming the best case scenario* where Wartortle is only 9.5 levels behind Squirtle, you will have to power up Wartortle 19 times to get him to the same level (each power up raises the level by 0.5).

Powering up Wartortle will cost you both candy and stardust. By looking at [this chart](http://pokemongo.gamepress.gg/power-up-costs), I can determine how much each power up will cost, and then calculate the total cost. C= candy; SD = stardust

- 5 to 6.5 will cost: 1 C + 600 SD per power up. (4 times = 4 C + 2400 SD)
- 7 to 8.5 will cost: 1 C + 800 SD per power up. (4 times = 4 C + 3200 SD)
- 9 to 10.5 will cost: 1 C + 1000 SD per power up. (4 times = 4 C + 4000 SD)
- 11 to 12.5 will cost: 2 C + 1300 SD per power up. (4 times = 8 C + 5200 SD)
- 13 to 14.5 will cost: 2 C + 1600 SD per power up. (3 times = 6 C + 4800 SD)

If you have to get him from level 5 to 14.5, the total cost would be 26 candy and 19,600 stardust.

Therefore, evolving Squirtle is a better choice because that only costs 25 candy to end up with a Wartortle with high CP.

Answer (score 1):

It will take more candies but you'll want to evolve your Squirtle. The CP scale will stay consistant through an evolution. So let's say the Squirtle is 80% on the CP scale and the Wartortle is at 40%. If you evolve Squirtle it would stay at the 80% point and the CP would be at that point as well.

> This circle essentially shows what could be considered as the
>   Pokémon's Level and can be increased. When a Pokémon evolves, the
>   placement in the semi circle will remain the same, but the Pokémon's
>   CP will likely increase based on the Pokémon's base stats.

http://www.serebii.net/pokemongo/combatpoints.shtml

Answer (score 1):

What I can piece together is that better Pokemon end up stronger and a better level than raw Pokemon.

Example:
I have a level 60 Weedle and a Level 43 Kakuna. I will feed the Kakuna more instead of the Weedle.
The Weedle has to go through an evolution. While that is nice, it won't go to a Beedril immediately.
The Kakuna's level improves it AND the beedril once it evolves.

Comment: Star dust is used for every pokemon so it's best to save it, evolving is relatively cheap since it only costs candies (plus it gives you a decent amount of xp). If you have enough candy it would be better to evolve your weedle twice.